# What does the following code mean in c++?

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

```
struct Dog{  
  int a;  
  int b;  
};

int Dog::*location = &Dog::a  
Dog* obj1 = new Dog;  
obj1->*location = 3;
```

what does `&Dog::a` refer to?

Comment: I can already see a "poor sportsmanship" badge in my future due to "experts" who don't know what they don't know :(

Comment: @Ben: Decipher that for me? :)

Comment: @GMan: I've voted on four competing answers.  +1 and -3.  Actually, I guess that would still be credit toward the [Sportsmanship](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/805/sportsmanship) badge, if I didn't already have it.

Comment: dynamic allocation is not necessary here, `Dog obj1; obj1.*location = 3` would work fine too.

Answer (score 4):

It creates a pointer-to-member, which is like a pointer to a data member of a class, but the class instance isn't determined yet, it's just the offset.  (Note, when combined with multiple inheritance or virtual inheritance, it gets quite a bit more complicated than a simple offset.  But the compiler works out the details.)

Notice the pointer-to-member dereference operator `->*` used in the last line, where the class instance is combined with the pointer-to-member to yield a particular data member of a particular instance.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `location` is known as "member data pointer". It's a pointer to something inside a structure, but doesn't make sense unless it's used with an *actual* object pointer. The use of `*location` by itself would not be enough information to resolve to an actual address, but `obj1->*location` refers to an actual location.

Answer (score -2):

& means take the adress of something.

Comment: Well it may be a bit terse, but it's true, so why -1?

Comment: probably because it does not answer the question but only gives some detail :)

Comment: @GMan: Because it doesn't yield an address, when used to form a pointer-to-member.

Comment: @Ben: Eh, I'll give you that one, especially considering: §3.9.2/3: "Except for pointers to static members, text referring to “pointers” does not apply to pointers to members." I will say that I'd agree with the answer canonically, though, but you're right.

Comment: @Marino: Sometimes.  `&((Dog*)(0))->a` is the expression generally used to find the offset.  But pointers-to-members can be used polymorphically, in which case they're more than just an offset.